# Problems with code when trying fix it binary in R

Tags: r

I tried to count amount of individuals that have answer <=2. When I do it with `length(which(healthProb$healthProblem <=2))`

I got answer 253. And when I transform them as binary where <=2 is 1 I got answer that there is zero individuals that are coded as 1. How can I fix my binary code?

Binary code:

```
healthProb <- data.frame(healthProb, binary = 0)
rows_under_2 <- which(healthProb$healthProblem <= 2)
dat4[rows_under_2, 3] <- 1
table(healthProb$binary)
```

Head of my dataframe:

```
Organisation healthProblem binary
1       xxxx             1      0
2       xxxx             3      0
3       xxxx             5      0
4       xxxx             3      0
5       xxxx             4      0
6       xxxx             4      0
```

Comment: Are `dat4` and `healthProb` same datasets? I would use something like this - `data$binary <- as.numeric(data$healthProblem <= 2)`

Comment: No, I actually did not even realize that I had it there. How stupid I feel now. Thank you that you noticed it, now I have right numbers!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
df <- within(df,binary <- ifelse(healthProblem<=2,1,0))
```

or a faster approach (thanks to @PoGibas)

```
df <- within(df,binary <- as.numeric(healthProblem<=2))
```

which gives

```
> df
  Organisation healthProblem binary
1         xxxx             1      1
2         xxxx             3      0
3         xxxx             5      0
4         xxxx             3      0
5         xxxx             4      0
6         xxxx             4      0
```

**DATA**

```
df<-structure(list(Organisation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "xxxx", class = "factor"), healthProblem = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L), binary = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: `as.numeric` is way way faster than `ifelse` (check with microbenchmark). Also, OPs problems is not reproducible.

Comment: @PoGibas Thanks! Your advice is added to the solution